# Length of divisors of big numbers(Runtime Error while trying big numbers)

Tags: python, algorithm, math

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnljL.png)

[Here is question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpKml.png)

Why this method works slowly. Is there any fastest way of finding length of divisors

Comment: Please don't post code as images and definitely not linked from another site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well `range` function always accepts int as its arguments, but the division inside `range` function always outputs a float.
Try this:

```
math.ceil(float_number)
```

because as you `range` function does not cover the upper-range number.
Moreover, you have to include number 1 in your `range` function as well; that is, change your `range` function to this:

```
range(1, n+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

How can a number *n* have an odd number of divisors? If *p* is a divisor of *n*, then there is some integer *q* such that *pq* = *n*. *q* is also a divisor of *n* so divisors always come in pairs, and so the total number of divisors must be even... *unless* one of the pairs consists of the same number twice, so that *pp* = *n*.

In other words, a number has an odd number of divisors if and only if it is a perfect square. But you can certainly check that in much less time than it takes to loop through all the possible divisors.